# Imitate MessageBox - waiting for user's choice

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await

I'm working mostly with Windows Phone and I'm trying to create something similar to MessageBox - small window that apperas and waits for user's choice (the Thread that invoked window waits). I found three ways how I can achive this goal:
*FIRST* - TaskCompletionSource
In this case my Task looks like this:

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
private async Task myTask1()
{
   window.Show(); // Show window
   await taskComplete.Task;
   //some job run after User's choice
   MessageBox.Show("Job finished");
}
```

And my window's Closed event:

```
private void WindowClosedEvent1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   taskComplete.SetResult(true);
}
```

*SECOND* - SemaphoreSlim
My Task and event:

```
private SemaphoreSlim mySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
private async Task myTask2()
{
    window.Show(); // Show window
    await mySemaphore.WaitAsync();
    //some job run after User's choice
    MessageBox.Show("Job finished");
}

private void WindowClosedEvent2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mySemaphore.Release();
}
```

*THIRD* - EventWaitHandle:
My Task and Event:

```
EventWaitHandle waitForUser = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "myEventName");
private async Task myTask3()
{
    window.Show(); // Show window
    await Task.Run(() => waitForUser.WaitOne());
    //some job run after User's choice
    MessageBox.Show("Job finished");
}

private void WindowClosedEvent3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    waitForUser.Set();
}
```

All three methods work, but I cannot decide which to use. I'm mostly thinking that 1) or 2) will be the best choice. Can any of those three methods cause troubles in some circumstances? Has anybody tried something like this?

Comment: Why does it have to be sync? Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20917996/1768303 ?

Comment: @Noseratio I'm working now with Windows Phone, and as far as I know, there is no ShowDialog - that's why I'm trying this code above. It works, but I'm new to asynchronous programming and I've some doubts and there may be many things I'm not aware of.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WinPhone development but in most GUI frameworks, calling any GUI functions from background threads is a no-no (all GUI stuff must be on one thread). Something to watch out for, unless WinPhone doesn't work that way, in which case disregard!

Comment: Now that you've clarified it's WP, there is `MessageDialog` and `Popup`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx

Comment: @dvnrrs You are right - it works much the same. In this case I'm running this on UI thread. What is important to me, that code after await is not run before I close my window. I've to run it async - UI is not blocked, which enables me to close window and after that the rest of the job is proceed.

Comment: @Noseratio You are right, there is PopUp, but it works pretty much the same as my window - program doesn't wait for user's choice, so I'm at the same point.

Comment: You're on the right way with your first approach. The question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17795284/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio All three approaches work. I'm looking for possible troubles with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant #1 with `TaskCompletionSource` is enough for this, that's what `TaskCompletionSource` is for. #2 and #3 are unnecessary complex, especially #3 with `Task.Run(..)`, which is wasting a pool thread for a blocking wait.

Because there is no modality for `Popup` in WP, all three approaches potentially have one major issue: re-entrancy. E.g., if `myTask2()` is called upon a button click, nothing prevents user from clicking that button again, which would start another `myTask2()`. The UI workflow of your app should account for this. This is discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e625607f-788f-45d0-b9b6-fc4dbe96ac64/modal-popup?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Comment: I thought about this problem and tried some more things, and I admit that TaskCompletionSource will be the best for this - the other advantage of this is that I can pass result with it. And you are right that in every approach UI must be thought out.