# How to create Messagebox type class?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, metadata, messagebox

I am trying to develop my own Messagebox type. Even though I create Windows Phone User Control I need to declare it as a object and show. Moreover, I cannot hold the application when I'm using it as a object. Therefore, I want to create message box prompt that helps to hold an application and show to user. I don't want to use third party Tools.

The current MessageBox class is a metadata class.

So how do I create Metadata class that helps me to do this?

Or in other words, how to create a MessageBox that exactly look a like System Runtime MessageBox but with more elements?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create you own MessageBox it is quite a long way (many things you have to consider if you want to handle all exceptions) but of course it is possible.

For this purpose you won't be able to use MessageBox. You may be interested in [PopUp class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup). [Here is a short example](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone) how to use it in WP.

The second approach is to use a designed control in the visual tree. More about methods you can read in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456394.aspx).

There are a lot of things you have to consider:

- waiting for user's choice - not blocking the main thread (you can read [something about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21222629/2681948))
- handle more messages at one time?
- disabling ApplicationBar / hiding it?
- watch out for SystemTray
- think about Thread-Safety
- returning result
- handling BackKey and Navigation

Those above are only few main things (IMO), there will be more, but it is a very nice task ;) Good luck.

Comment: I really appreciate what you have given me but I have tried the PopUp Class too, also declare pages as object too. But I wanna do that one. I think my mind is set..! Do you have any bit extra information?

Comment: @gayan1991 And what is wrong with PopUp? I've played with it a little and I think it is possible to make 'almost' the same looking  one as MessageBox. And you can customize it as you wish.

Comment: PopUp is fine, it can give pretty much stuff....! but I wanna use static type. When User made his i wanna get that rightaway for the next operation. in the main page. it's more like RadInputPrompt, which allow user to enter information and do things like suddent search stuff.

Comment: @gayan1991 Then make a singleton which will Show your popup. You can acquire frame and page in the Show method - then only add Popup class to your page and here you go.